# Displaying UTF8 Character on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Config.php

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF8';
```

database.php

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

html header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

my database has the collation of utf8_general_ci and my all files are encoded on utf8 even though i could not display my unicode character on my page

this always displays 
à¤µà¤¿.à¤¸à¤‚. à¥¨à¥¦à¥§à¥ª à¤¸à¤¾à¤²à¤®à¤¾

Comment: Is UTF-8 enabled in php.ini? Also, $config['charset'] should be set to 'UTF-8' instead of 'UTF8' if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Are you setting the charset in your HTML pages <head>? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure you have utf8 everywhere, like
**in config.php**

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8"; //not UTF8
```

**in php.ini**

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

**for database**

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: thank you very much sir... nepali ma text na aayera last tension bhako thiyo... :)

Comment: hehe , glad to know it worked for you... yea dimaag kharaab garney issue yestai ho .. simple cha but easily skip huncha dimaag baata.. :)

Comment: @Sld G'tam English please

Comment: Worked for me! Been a pain from past day.